# Custom vi command: How to insert current date with a variable's content?

Tags: linux, shell, vim, vi

I'm new to the `vi` editor and I would like to create a simple custom command in `.vimrc` that inserts something like `2012-03-13 22:21:17.0 +0100 / Daniel`.

Actually, my command (in `.vimrc`) is as follows:

```
command! InsertTime :normal a<C-R>=strftime('%F %H:%M:%S.0 %z')<CR>
```

I also set a variable:

```
let myname="Daniel"
```

`InsertTime` inserts the date perfectly. But how can I concatenate it with the content of my variable?

Comment: Im not sure try add .myname at the end of your command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To concatenate, vim scripts use `.` caracter. So try this one :

In vimrc:

```
let myname="Daniel"
command! InsertTime :normal a<C-R>=strftime('%F %H:%M:%S.0 %z') . "/" . myname<CR>
```

no tested there.

Comment: What is your trigger ? `:normal a` ?

Comment: What happens if `myname` is not defined?

Answer (score 2):

Since you said you're new to "vim" I am going to assume you don't know any of the things I'm about tell you.  Mucho sorry if you already know them.

If you're going to do this a lot (insert the line "%F %H:%M:%S.0 %z / Daniel"), instead of defining a command, which you have to invoke with a `:command_name`, define a macro and/or an input macro that can be invoked with just two or three character.

To define an input macro, do the following at the ':' prompt, or add it to your $HOME/.exrc or $HOME/.vimrc file (without the preceding ':'):

```
:map <C-X><C-X> Go<ESC>!!date '+\%F \%H:\%M:\%S.0 \%z'<CR>A / Daniel<ESC>
```

Now when you're in "vi" (but not in input mode), typing `control-Xcontrol-X` will:

```
G            go to last line in file; replace this with the "motion" keys sequence appropriate for your use (or nothing at all if you want to append the line right after the cursor)
o            open a new line
<ESC>        escape out of input mode
!!date ...   invoke the date command, replace the current line with its stdout (output)
A            append at the end of the line (now having the "date")
 / Dan...    verbatim intput text
<ESC>      escape out of input mode
```

`control-Xcontrol-X` can be some unusual sequence that you'd normally not use for anything, nor used by any "vi" operation that you might use.  I use  as the first character, because in "vi",  decrements the next integer on the line after the cursor, if any.  That is something I hardly ever do.  I define my macros to be invoked with `<C-X><C-B>`, `<C-X><C-D>`, `<C-X>s1`, etc.

To create an input macro, well, that's another whole long subject, and I'm tired of typing today, so, another day.  :)